# Why do we need a firewall if no programs are running on your ports?

Tags: networking, security, firewall

When I try to telnet to a port on a server, and if there is no program listening on that port telnet dies with a "Unable to connect ... " error. I understand that. But, why do we need a firewall if there is no program listening on any ports?

Comment: Defense in Depth.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defense_in_Depth_(computing)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

There may not be a service running right now, but how about tomorrow?  You have them all turned off, but what about your users?  Anyone on a unix/windows/mac system can open a port > 1024 on any machine they have access to.  What about malware?  What about a virus?   They can also open up ports and start serving information to the world, or start listening for connections from the network.

A firewall's main purpose is not to block the ports for services you know are disabled, it is to block the ports on services you might not know about.  Think of it as a default *deny* with only certain holes punched in for services you authorize.  Any user or program started by a user can start a server on a system they have access to, a firewall prevents someone else from connecting to that service.

A good admin knows what services need to be exposed, and can enable them.  A firewall is mostly to mitigate the risk from unknown servers running on your system or your network, as well as to manage what is allowed into the network from a central place.

It's important to know what is running on your machine/server and only enable what you need, but a firewall provides that extra bit of protection against the things you don't know about.

Comment: > "Any user or program started by a user can start a server on a system they have access to, a firewall prevents someone else from connecting to that service."
But, wouldn't this make the service unusable?

Comment: @KhajaMinhajuddin yes! That's exactly the point.  (-:

Comment: @KhajaMinhajuddin You only want services that *you* setup to be available to the world.  You don't want the smtp server that super_spam_virus.exe started while you weren't looking listening for connections from other infected systems.  A firewall will prevent this, though it's not a panacea.

Comment: super_spam_virus.exe doesn't sound like Unix & Linux :)

Comment: @userunknown true... how about a.out, or a compromised version of /bin/ls that was copied to your system. Or, if you're a developer `hg serve` which starts a webserver on your machine. Point is, it's trivial to start a server on any machine whether it's used as a 'desktop' or a 'server' doesn't matter. And once that server is started, and you don't know about it... well, that's when the fun starts.

Comment: Well of course, there is an important distinction between servers, between a corporate network, and a single user desktop machine. I don't know how a malicious /bin/ls should enter my system if it isn't already compromised. And in a corporate network a user would normally not be exposed to the outside with his desktop machine, but YES, I would set up a firewall or maybe more than one in such a network too. But not personal firewalls, and not on the client (which isn't what you suggested). But the precondition was `no program listening on any port.`

Answer (score 3):

IF there is no program listening on any port, you don't need a firewall, but you also can't connect to your server because it is 'sealed' from the rest of the world.

On the other hand ... let's say your server does not have any locally running program listening on any port, but it serves as a gateway for other computers behind it. In this case you use a firewall to manage the masquerading (NAT) and optionally you can filter some stuff on packet forwarding.

Comment: This is a good point, but if I want the server to do stuff( I usually would put openssh and a webserver). Even with a firewall, I have to open ports to make the running apps like openssh and webservers useful. So, I guess what I am asking is, Are there any programs which open up ports to the outside world which need to be blocked by a firewall and which would still be useful.

Comment: Yes there are. Not necessary an example for a server, but let's presume you have a Linux machine with X installed, and X running on a network port. You would want to allow your computer, maybe some other computers from the LAN to connect to your X. However you would not want Joe from France to connect to it. Another example, let's say you set up multiple VPN services on your server and you need to control which networks can see other networks (or not to see). Or, let's say you have OpenSSH but you want to allow connection only from your home computer. There are many other examples.

Comment: @KhajaMinhajuddin: For ssh, you should use the `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` to secure the machine. `PermitRootLogin` should be set to No, you should use a secure password and maintain the machine with sudo (you may use sudo after logging in with an account with sudo permissions). Setting the restrictions with a firewall is just the wrong tool for the job. The same would be true for a `postgresql` database: Use the database configuration, to set and revoke permissions.

Answer (score 2):

Strictly speaking it may not be necessary, however, keep in mind that a firewall can provide more functionality than simply refusing connections over network ports. For example, DROP versus REJECT behavior.

Comment: What is the advantage of DROP versus REJECT?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I believe DROP just doesn't respond so the requester doesn't even know if the request was received or if your machine exists.  REJECT says you're definitely there and just don't want to talk about it.  And, if something's behind a locked door, it might be worth trying to find a way in to find out what's worth protecting.

Answer (score -4):

> But, why do we need a firewall if there is no program listening on any ports?

If you have a **Single-User Desktop**, not a server, you don't need a firewall, if there is no service running, as on a default Ubuntu installation.

Windows had some times, after being able to do networking, some services running on default for maintenance, updates, internal message passing and so on. You couldn't stop them, without stopping windows working, but they where vulnerable for external attacks. So the windows users needed a firewall, and the meme, that everybody needs a firewall, spread fast.

When they met the Linux folks, which often were server admins, they didn't say 'you don't need a firewall on linux' but 'we have free firewalls like iptables for nearly a decade'.

A **personal firewall**, sitting on the system it shall protect, isn't the best idea either.

#### On a single user desktop system, you don't need a personal firewall.

Comment: Look at the answer from gabe and rethink. Especially the Desktop clients are vulnerable to attacks.

Comment: @userunknown: a virus might be a user of your desktop. A daemon that you install and fail to configure is too.

Comment: a) There has not been a linux virus in the wild for quite some time, or do you know any actual one (last 5 years)? b) If there is a virus on my system, it is to late to defend against, I guess.

Comment: It is certainly not true that "there has not been a linux virus in the wild for quite some time"  - see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Badbunny_(computer_worm) for one example. Also, a firewall might prevent a virus which is on your system from doing some of the malicious things it's designed to do (call home for updates, distribute itself around your network, send ANYTHING anywhere) - it's "not too late".

Comment: Longer linux virus listing here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_malware

Comment: @TimothyJones: Please don't confuse Worms with viruses. And the second list talks about infection of the apache web server, which is, as the name states, a server - not a desktop application. The page itself claims: `However, few if any are in the wild`.

Comment: @TimothyJones: I'm not a malware author, but if I would write something, which sends malicious code to somewhere, I would use port 80, which is surely not blocked on a router in a home network. You're just spreading FUD.

Comment: I have run security testing for many years, and access through desktops is a very useful route to propagate an attack. Doesn't matter if it's Windows, Linux, Solaris, whatever. Lock it down or lose it to an attacker. The correct phrase should be **you may need a firewall on your desktop - fully assess the risks in your environment**

Comment: @RoryAlsop: What is your concern exactly? If I don't have a daemon running and listening on a port, I don't need a firewall to protect it. If I have some malware running, it's already to late. Stopping outgoing traffic is useless, because I have to allow outgoing traffic if I use http, https, email, ftp, skype, gajim and so on - trivial to hide other traffic, if I have malware. You can not compare it to Windows-PCs, which opened ports for internal stuff, AFAIK with the first version of XP, but fixed it meanwhile. Without firewall, your Windows-PC was infected in seconds.

Comment: @Nils: Did you mention that I wrote `desktop` 2 times in bold? Who do you think are the users of my desktop?

Comment: @userunknown just because you use a computer as a `desktop` doesn't mean it's not still a `server` those are just words.  Your `desktop` has plenty of `servers` that could potentially run on it, and possibly that already are.

Comment: @gabe: I have nmap to check for open ports, and the condition, mentioned in the question was `no program listening on any port`. You can't close a door, which isn't there. A potentially running server isn't running, and since most people sit behind a DSL-router today, their network interface isn't exposed at all to the outside world, without setting this router up. `Personal firewalls` are mostly snakeoil and shouldn't be suggested for persons, who don't run a server.

Comment: Think about CUPS (any linux), SLPD (SuSE) and other stuff (KDE-remote, iSCSI-server/client) that may be running on linux after an update. Even if you checked before these things may appear. If they do it is good to block them. BTW - activate your firewall via GUI  (don`t allow anything) on RedHat, start CUPS and see if you can connect to it from outside. Then look at `iptables-save`: Voila - the CUPS port is open without showing up in the gui...

Comment: A fine Linux installation, for example Ubuntu, does not route traffic from the internet to the printer. CUPS only listens to the local net, if at all. If you want to heal a misconfigured CUPS with a firewall, you're doing it wrong. Instead complain upstream, to fix the bug not only for yourself, but for the whole community of your distribution. I don't use or know SLPD or iSCSI so I can't say much about that, but I would be surprised if anonymous, remote users had access to my SCSI hardware - do they? Arguing with a unforeseeable future, where security might be lowered ...

Comment: ... doesn't look plausible to me. My first Linuxes around 1998 where running httpd by default, and had inetd up and running, but people hadn't internet flat rates over then. This times have passed long ago. Long ago. You and the others only have movie plots in mind, what could happen if ... - but these ifs are unreasonable. I could as well ask, what happens if your firewall is buggy. Maybe you introduce the security risks by installing such a thing.